# Redirect issue, keeps adding string to url because of wrong rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a link: /oldlink/ that needs to be directed to /oldlink/general but if I do this code in my htaccess there is an infinite loop because it keeps adding /general/general/general behind my URL.

```
Redirect 301 /oldlink/ /oldlink/general/
```

Is there some kind of code I can add to let it stop adding extra string to the url? Maybe a rewrite instead of a redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your redirect pattern also matches the destination url. You need to use RedirectMatch instead of Redirect directive to avoid the loop error

```
RedirectMatch ^/oldlink/?$ /oldlink/general/
```